# docomo APIによるraspepbrry piの音声会話

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

```py
　 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
　#マイク0番からの入力を受ける。一定時間(RECROD_SECONDS)だけ録音し、ファイル名：    mono.wavで保存する。

import pyaudio
import sys
import time
import wave
import requests
import os
import json

def recognize():
    url = "https://api.apigw.smt.docomo.ne.jp/amiVoice/v1/recognize?APIKEY={}".format(APIKEY)
    files = {"a": open(PATH, 'rb'), "v":"on"}
    r = requests.post(url, files=files)
    message = r.json()['text']
    print message
    return message

def dialogue(message="こんにちは"):    
    url = "https://api.apigw.smt.docomo.ne.jp/dialogue/v1/dialogue?APIKEY={}".format(APIKEY)
    payload = {
      "utt": message,
      "context": "",
      "nickname": "光",
      "nickname_y": "ヒカリ",
      "sex": "女",
      "bloodtype": "B",
      "birthdateY": "1997",
      "birthdateM": "5",
      "birthdateD": "30",
      "age": "16",
      "constellations": "双子座",
      "place": "東京",
      "mode": "dialog",
      "t":20
    }
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
    print r.json()['utt']
    return r.json()['utt']

def talk(message="こんにちは", card=1, device=0):        
    os.system('/home/pi/aquestalkpi/AquesTalkPi " ' + message.encode('utf-8') + ' " | aplay -Dhw:{},{}').format(card, device)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chunk = 1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    PATH = '/var/tmp/tmp.wav'
    APIKEY='xxxxxxxxxxxxx' #DocomoAPI Key
    CARD = 1 #OUTPUTの指定
    DEVICE = 0 #OUTPUTの指定

    #サンプリングレート、マイク性能に依存
    RATE = 16000
    #録音時間
    RECORD_SECONDS = input('Please input recoding time>>>')

    #pyaudio
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    #マイク0番を設定
    input_device_index = 0
    #マイクからデータ取得
    stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,
                    channels = CHANNELS,
                    rate = RATE,
                    input = True,
                    frames_per_buffer = chunk)
    all = []
    for i in range(0, RATE / chunk * RECORD_SECONDS):
        data = stream.read(chunk)
        all.append(data)

    stream.close()    
    data = ''.join(all)                    
    out = wave.open(PATH,'w')
    out.setnchannels(1) #mono
    out.setsampwidth(2) #16bits
    out.setframerate(RATE)
    out.writeframes(data)
    out.close()

    p.terminate()

    message = recognize()
    talk_message = dialogue(message)
    talk(talk_message, CARD, DEVICE)
```

以上のpythonを実行しようとすると

```
Please input recoding time>>>3
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started

こんにちは！話しかけてくれるのを待ってた
ALSA lib conf.c:1701:(snd_config_load1) :1:1:Unexpected }
ALSA lib conf.c:4722:(snd_config_expand) Parse arguments error: 無効な引数です
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hw:{},{}
aplay: main:722: audio open error: 無効な引数です
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dialogue_test.py", line 87, in <module>
    talk(talk_message, CARD, DEVICE)
  File "dialogue_test.py", line 43, in talk
    os.system('/home/pi/aquestalkpi/AquesTalkPi " ' + message.encode('utf-8') + ' " | aplay -Dhw:{},{}').format(card,device)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'format'
```

というふうに最後のところでエラーになってしまいます
どうすればいいでしょうか
P.S.
DcomoAPIKEYとRATEは正しく入力しています
参考サイトは[Qiita：簡単にできる！音声認識と音声合成を使ってRaspberrypiと会話](http://qiita.com/kinpira/items/75513eaab6eed19da9a3#ras%E3%82%BF%E3%82%BD%E3%81%A8%E4%BC%9A%E8%A9%B1%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E5%B7%BB)です
最初の大量の文字列（”こんにちは！話しかけてくれるのを待ってた”より前は警告
ですがエラーにはなっていないようなので無視していいと思います
使用していいるものは音声認識と対話にDocomo API　録音に　pyaudio　発声にAquestalkです
raspberry piを　使っています

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.system()`はプロセス、あるいはコマンドの終了ステータスが返されます。
参考：https://docs.python.jp/3/library/os.html#os.system

そのため、以下の部分の実行でエラーが発生しています。

```
os.system('/home/pi/aquestalkpi/AquesTalkPi " ' + message.encode('utf-8') + ' " | aplay -Dhw:{},{}').format(card, device)
```

---

追記

外部コマンドの実行結果として標準出力が必要であれば[subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)を利用すると良いと思います。

```
res = subprocess.check_output('/home/pi/aquestalkpi/AquesTalkPi " ' + message.encode('utf-8') + ' " | aplay -Dhw:{},{}', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Comment: NameError: global name 'subprocess' is not definedと出ます（実行しようとすると）どうすればいいでしょうか追記python　versionは2.7.9です。（知識が疎かですみません）

Comment: 先の問題は　import subprocessで解決出来ました　しかし今度はraise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/home/pi/aquestalkpi/AquesTalkPi " こんにちはー。ちょうど話したいと思ってた " | aplay -Dhw:{},{}' returned non-zero exit status 1
と出ますどうすればいいでしょうか

Comment: エラー内容の通りです。subprocess.check_outputの[ドキュメント](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)を確認してください。コマンドのリターンコードがゼロでないため、例外が発生しています。

Comment: 質問の本題とは逸れますが、エラーはプログラムのどこが悪いのかを教えてくれています。エラーが発生した時はそのエラーの内容を理解しようとすることが解決のための一番の近道です。

Comment: 参考になりました。ありがとうございます